# Is there a nicer way of referring to the object containing an object?

Tags: java

For a lot of the applications I've made so far, there are always classes that contain a bunch of other classes.  For example, I might have a Player class that has a Pet.  However, I want to be able to refer to the Player through the Pet sometimes.  The following code will work for this:

```
public class Player {
    Pet p;
    public Player() {
        p = new Pet(this);
    }
}

public class Pet {
    Player owner;
    public Pet(Player owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

If I want to refer to the Player through the Pet, then sure, I can just use the `owner` variable.  But is there a nicer way to do this?  I will often have classes containing classes containing classes, etc., so my Player class will own a Pet, which may have a Toy, and then the Toy has a reference to the Player.  And hell, I might even have classes above the Player, such as a Building in a City in the World.  So a Pet's Toy might have a reference to the entire World.  I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: This is basically how you do it though. You might want to make an encompassing EntityLiving class from which Pets and Players extend, and then a pet has an EntityLiving as owner, enabling npc's to have pets too. etc... And it's usual to have multiple references as needed and relevant. The toy wouldn't have a reference to the player as it's not relevant for the toy. A pet would own a toy, a toy would only know about the world. Or you would have a robot toy that follows the pet, then it would be logical to have a reference back to the owner, making the toy a pet type.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in details what are you trying to achieve? Because I have the feeling you should rethink how to model your class structure and hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Well, that really depends on scale. When your object model is pretty small, and you are (quite) sure, that there are no major enhancements to expect over the next months, or years ... then such simple "double bookkeeping" can be a reasonable answer.

But in more realistic scenarios: yes, that approach breaks quickly.

It then often helps to look into the ideas of domain driven design. First of all: look at what you are modelling. Sure, my pet dog knows me, but it doesn't know the concept of "owning", it doesn't know that I am his owner.

So, a first solution could be: simply drop that `owner` part from the Pet class. Instead, you *might* want to create some sort of index. In the most simple form, that could be a map. Some central registry is **told** that person X owns pet Y. Now your code can go and ask Y whether it knows the owner of X.

And coming back to DDD, there you talk about *aggregates*. Things that somehow belong together. But you can't just get to *any* of the members, you always have to go through some *root* element. See [here](https://airbrake.io/blog/software-design/domain-driven-design) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is a one-to-one relationship, you might be better off having an encapsulating object aggregating your pet, and your player. Or keep that double link between parent and child if your app isn't too big.

From your description about the city, the building and the world, I'm assuming the link can easily become a one-to-many and it can become tricky if it scales. In that case you might have to exernalize the linking to something like bi-directional maps. It's basically a map where you can get the value from the key as a normal map, but also get the key from the value. And in that case, you can link your dog and its pet easily.